# Proofing That The Sum Of The Squares Of The Equation $z^n=a$ is $0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Hello everyone $\omega_1 , \omega_2 , ... \omega_n$ are the solutions of the equation $z^n=a$

and I need to proof that for any $a$ and any $n\ge 2 \longrightarrow$  $\omega_1 + \omega_2 + ... +\omega_n = 0$ with the sum of Geometric progression.

What I tried to is mark $z = r\cdot cis(\theta) , a = s\cdot cis(\alpha)$
and I know that $z^n = r^n\cdot cis(\theta \cdot n) = s\cdot cis(\alpha)\longrightarrow \theta = \frac{\alpha +2\pi k}{n}$

but I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: I know that I can solve that with Vieta's formulas but I need to solve this with the sum of Geometric progression and De Moivre's formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\omega _1^2+\omega _2^2+\ldots+\omega _n^2=\left(\omega _1+\omega _2+\ldots+\omega _n\right)^2-2\left(\sum _{k=1}^n \sum _{h=k+1}^n \omega _h \omega _k\right)$$
In an algebraic equation with roots: $\omega _1,\omega _2,\ldots,\omega _n$

we know that the equation can be written as
$$\prod _{k=1}^n \left(z-\omega _k\right)=0$$
Expanding we get
$$z^n -\sum_{k=1}^n \omega_k z^{n-1} + \sum _{k=1}^n \sum _{h=k+1}^n \omega _h \omega _k z^{n-2}+\ldots=0$$
As the equation $z^n=a$ has all coefficients of $a_k=0,k=1,\ldots,n-1$, we can conclude that $$\omega _1^2+\omega _2^2+\ldots+\omega _n^2=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can write $\omega_k = a\cdot exp(\frac{2ki\pi}{n})$ and let $n$ be fixed. From this use can conclude that $\omega_k = \omega_1^k =\omega^k$ Using this and the geometric sum forumale you can conclude $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a\cdot\omega_k = a\sum_{k=1}^{n} \omega^k = a\frac{1-\omega^{n+1}}{1-\omega} = a\frac{1-exp(2ni\pi/n)}{1-exp(2i\pi/n)}$$
In the numberator you can reduce the $n$ inside the exp-function. Since $exp(2\pi i)=1$, your numerator equals $0$ and you are done.